# I'm looking for G2P conversion tool for vb .net framework windows forms able to return textual grapheme/phoneme pairs for a given English word

Tags: windows, nlp, vb.net

I'm developing a vb .net framework for windows forms application, and need to find a way to take an english word provided by the user, and split it into its grapheme/phoneme pairs.
There are libraries that pair words to their phonemes, but no library pairing the individual graphemes of the words to their respective phonemes is available, nor the pairing is possible algorithmically ( without some kind of LLM). G2P conversion tools are available in python, but I couldn't find a working example to guide me in my quest.